# Basic Prolog - Arbitrary amount of atoms (new to Prolog)

Tags: prolog

```
palindrome_list_atomes(A,B):-  
  atom_concat(A,B,C),  
  atom_chars(C,X),  
  palindrome_list(X).
```

I want to make it so palindrome_list_atomes(A,B) will except any amount of Atoms (not just A and B), and then atom_concat will add these relative number of atoms together to create a atom C.

```
atom_charts(C,X)
```

just converts it into a list of Chars and X is then passed into another predicate.

Im sure something like this is easy (as it should be), I'm just new to Prolog and getting fed up of reaching dead ends on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you must pass a list of atoms:

```
palindrome_list_atomes(Atoms):-  
  list_concat(Atoms, Big),  
  atom_chars(Big,Chars),
  palindrome_list(Chars).

list_concat([], '').
list_concat([A|As], R) :-
  list_concat(As, T),
  atom_concat(A, T, R).
```

list_concat/2 it's a poor man replacement of [atomic_list_concat](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/2)/2, available in SWI-Prolog' library. Of course, use the builtin if available.